# Chrome Extensions. Как проверить, существуют ли cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookie, chrome-extension

```
//cохраняю куки
chrome.cookies.set({ url: "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/", name: "test", value: JSON.stringify({link: "OK" })});

//извлекаю куки
function getCookies(domain, name, callback) {
        chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
            if(callback) {
                callback(cookie.value);
            }
        });
    }

var check_cookies = getCookies("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/", "test", function(id) {
    console.log("id: " + id);
});

//если кук нет, выполнить действие
if (!check_cookies){
    выполнить действие
}
```

Нужно проверить, есть ли сохраненные куки для сайта (содержимое куки не важно, важно само их наличие).

Comment: В `api` такого метода нет, а значит Вам придется создать самому. Я не знаю конкретно Вашу ситуацию, но нужно получить куки и уже проверять есть ли они или есть ли в них что-то что нужно Вам.

Comment: @olmerdale, мне нужно проверить, есть ли они вообще

Answer (score 0):

Нативно можно проверить на наличие cookie вот так:

```
if (chrome.cookie.indexOf("check_cookies") >= 0) {
  // если куки были, то...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.cookies.get({ url: "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/", name: "test" }, function (cookie) {
    if (!cookie) {
        // выполнить действие;
        console.log('Can\'t get cookie!');
    } else {
        console.log(cookie.value);
    }
});
```